# Generate all combinations of pairs without redundancy

Tags: java, algorithm, combinations

I have to resolve a problem for an open-source championship software (in java). This software can find the best combination of matches with differents criteria (ranking of participants, matches already played ?, ...).

Currently, the used algorithm is not optimal because it compare all combinations of matches (including redundant combinations). With this approach, the sotfware compare "factorial of the number of participants" combinations. I'm looking for an algorithm which generate all combinations of matches without redundancy.

Current code with an example with 4 participants :

```
// Example with 4 participants
public static void main (String[] args) {
   String[] participants = {"A","B","C","D"};
   double factorial = factorial(participants.length);
   for(double i=0;i<factorial;i++) {
      String[] combination = permutation(i,participants);
      System.out.println("Combination "+(int)i+" : "+combination[0]+" vs "+combination[1]+", "+combination[2]+" vs "+combination[3]);
   }
}

// Current code
public static <K> K[] permutation (double k, K[] objects) {
   K[] permutation = objects.clone();
   for (int i = 2; i < permutation.length + 1; i++) {
      k = k / (i - 1);
      swap(permutation, (int)(k % i), i - 1);
   }
   return permutation;
}
public static <K> void swap (K[] objects, int indexA, int indexB) {
   K temp = objects[indexA];
   objects[indexA] = objects[indexB];
   objects[indexB] = temp;
}
public static double factorial (int value) {
   double result = value;
   while (value != 2) {
      result *= --value;
   }
   return result;
}
```

Output :

```
Combination 0 : D vs A, B vs C
Combination 1 : D vs B, A vs C
Combination 2 : D vs C, A vs B
Combination 3 : D vs C, B vs A
Combination 4 : D vs A, C vs B
Combination 5 : D vs B, C vs A
Combination 6 : C vs D, B vs A
Combination 7 : C vs D, A vs B
Combination 8 : B vs D, A vs C
Combination 9 : A vs D, B vs C
Combination 10 : B vs D, C vs A
Combination 11 : A vs D, C vs B
Combination 12 : C vs A, D vs B
Combination 13 : C vs B, D vs A
Combination 14 : B vs C, D vs A
Combination 15 : A vs C, D vs B
Combination 16 : B vs A, D vs C
Combination 17 : A vs B, D vs C
Combination 18 : C vs A, B vs D
Combination 19 : C vs B, A vs D
Combination 20 : B vs C, A vs D
Combination 21 : A vs C, B vs D
Combination 22 : B vs A, C vs D
Combination 23 : A vs B, C vs D
```

As you can see, there is a lot of redundancy ("A vs B, C vs D" is the same as "B vs A, C vs D" and "B vs A, D vs C" and ...). For 10 participants or more (10! = 3.628.800...), the lost time of comparison of each combination (with the aim of find the best) is considerable.

Example of desired output (order no matter) :

```
Combination 0 : A vs B, C vs D
Combination 1 : A vs C, B vs D
Combination 2 : A vs D, B vs C
```

Your help is welcome.

Comment: If you want *combinations*, then why are you using a *permutation* function?

Comment: This algorithm is the only I found a couple of years ago. It is not perfect but it's work. Now I need help to improve it. I make at lot of research but I find nothing to solve my problem...

Comment: And why is `A vs D, C vs B` not a desired output?

Comment: The desired output is all combinations of matches without redundancy. In my example of a championship with 4 participants, two combinations are sufficient to cover all possibilities (order no matter).

Comment: You're right, I made a mistake. Three combinations are necessary to cover all possibilities. I corrected my question by adding a combination. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to my question :

```
public void generate (int n) {
   int[] covered = new int[n];
   int[] list = new int[n];
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      covered[i] = 0;
   }
   this.generate(n, covered, 0, list);
}
private void generate (int n, int[] covered, int i, int[] list) {
   int j = 0;
   while ((j < n) && (covered[j] == 1)) {
      j++;
   }
   if (j == n) {
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));
      return;
   }
   covered[j] = 1;
   for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
      if (covered[k] == 0) {
         covered[k] = 1;
         list[i++] = j;
         list[i++] = k;
         this.generate(n, covered, i, list);
         i -= 2;
         covered[k] = 0;
      }
   }
   covered[j] = 0;
}
```

Found [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11/generating-combinations-from-a-set-of-pairs-without-repetition-of-elements).